# How do I get my embedded YouTube iframes to scale?

Tags: html, visual-studio, css, youtube

My website looks great... until I change resolutions or browsers, and suddenly the YouTube videos are comically out of proportion. Everything else scales well and I can't get them to scale at all. I tried setting them to a percentage but then they just scale to the nearest container (video), which also refuses to scale in height by percentage.

```
<aside id="video">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-i3mX0YRrjM" width="320" height="190"></iframe>
</aside>

#video {
margin: auto;
width:320px;
height:190px;
box-shadow: 15px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="container">
<aside id="video">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-i3mX0YRrjM" width="320" height="190"></iframe>
</aside>
</div>

#container {
margin:auto;
width:50%;
}

#video {
margin:auto;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 25px;
box-shadow: 15px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
#video iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Just adjust the #container width in the CSS to adjust the size.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, if you specify only height or width, the other will then adjust to scale.   When you specify both, they do not.

If you adjust your code above to, for example, only specify the width of the objects...  does the height auto-scale to meet your needs?

Comment: Nah, scales to the default value, which I think is 150px. But I eventually came up with a solution. I'll post it.

Comment: And by eventually, I mean, just now. I've been working on this for days, lol.